# Parsing text in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Enron email data from kaggle.
https://www.kaggle.com/wcukierski/enron-email-dataset
I am reading emails.csv file.I am using BeautifulSoup to parse the message column.

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv( "C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Documents\NLP\enron-email-dataset (1)\emails.csv")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
message=train["message"]
message[0]
soup = BeautifulSoup(message[0],"lxml")
message=soup.body.p
print message
```

First line parsed by beautifulsoup prints the following output

```
<p>Message-ID: &lt;18782981.1075855378110.JavaMail.evans@thyme&gt;
Date: Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)
From: phillip.allen@enron.com
To: tim.belden@enron.com
Subject: 
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Phillip K Allen
X-To: Tim Belden <tim belden="">
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \Phillip_Allen_Jan2002_1\Allen, Phillip K.\'Sent Mail
X-Origin: Allen-P
X-FileName: pallen (Non-Privileged).pst

Here is our forecast

 </tim></p>
```

I need to extract only this line
Here is our forecast

The line followed by X-FileName

How to parse the text and retrieve the specific portion.

Comment: I would use regex to do the extraction of the portion of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need data from a text inside p tag which is in some particular format use regex module

```
import re  
text = re.findall(r'X-FileName.*\n+(.*)',soup.body.p.getText())
```

The regex capture the `r'X-FileName.*\n+(.*)'` search for the line starting with X-FileName followed with one or new lines and `(.*)` captures the line that you want in your result.
This will result in the output

```
 >>>print(text)  
 ['Here is our forecast']
```

To capture multilple lines output till `</p>` tag use this regex. Here our strategy is to to collect all the lines after X-FileName line. So we are considering whole p tag rather than just text inside p tag.

```
text = re.findall('X-FileName[^\n]*(.*)?<\/p>',soup.body.p,re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Hi @Rajan Chauhan,Thanks for the help.The code above works fine for a single line.But what if message spans multiple lines.                                       X-FileName: pallen.nsf

Mr. Buckner,

 For delivered gas behind San Diego, Enron Energy Services is the appropriate 
Enron entity.  I have forwarded your request to Zarin Imam at EES.  Her phone 
number is 713-853-7107.  </p>                                                                 Here only Mr.Bucker string is parsed.What should I do if I need to extract the entire string following X-FileName:

Comment: @Jayashree See above i have added multiline support

Comment: When i use multi line syntax I am getting empty list.But when I remove p tag I am getting desired result.text = re.findall('X-FileName[^\n]*(.*)?',soup.body.p.getText(),re.DOTALL).Can you explain me the code?Thanks

Comment: @Jayshree Check this out